# Are the commas correctly used in this sentence?

Tags: commas

Even though there were lots of scientific, philosophical, and medicinal advances in the Baroque era, strict rules, established manners, and careful dress codes were placed on society.

Comment: Please link to the style guide you're using as the standard for 'correctness', and point out the conflicting elements of that style guide or explain why a particular point of that style guide is ambiguous in relation to your quote.

Comment: Why do you think they may not have been in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The commas are used correctly.

The one after *era* is used to indicate the end of the sub-clause. The rest are used for itemization (listing comma).

Note that the comma used before *and* is called *the Oxford comma*. This type of comma is used before a conjunction (usually, “and” and “or”) in a list of three or more items before the last term. The Oxford comma is typical of American English. In British English it is sometimes omitted.

Comment: Err, you know why it's called the "Oxford comma" right? Saying it's omitted in British English is just not true. It may not be as frequently used as in the US, but it most certainly is used by many here, including myself.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer.